# SQL Query to return rows matching any or all of a filter but not having more than the filter

Tags: sql, t-sql

A simplified scenario of what I'm trying to do is this:

I have a single column table that represents a filter.

I want to select from a table and only include rows that join onto a table that matches 1 or more of the filter values, but also exclude result where values are present that aren't in the filter.

Eg: My desired results here would be

```
MovieA
MovieB
```

Can anyone help out with the query.

```
CREATE TABLE [Movie] (Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE [Actor] (Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE [Character] (Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, Movie VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, Actor VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO Movie (Name) VALUES ('MovieA'), ('MovieB'), ('MovieC')
INSERT INTO Actor (Name) VALUES ('Bob'), ('Fred'), ('Sally')
INSERT INTO [Character] (Name, Movie, Actor) VALUES ('BobA', 'MovieA', 'Bob')
INSERT INTO [Character] (Name, Movie, Actor) VALUES ('BobB', 'MovieB', 'Bob')
INSERT INTO [Character] (Name, Movie, Actor) VALUES ('BobC', 'MovieC', 'Bob')
INSERT INTO [Character] (Name, Movie, Actor) VALUES ('FredA', 'MovieA', 'Fred')
INSERT INTO [Character] (Name, Movie, Actor) VALUES ('FredC', 'MovieC', 'Fred')
INSERT INTO [Character] (Name, Movie, Actor) VALUES ('SallyC', 'MovieC', 'Sally')

CREATE TYPE [Names] AS TABLE([Name] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)

DECLARE @ActorNamesFilter dbo.Names
INSERT INTO @ActorNamesFilter (Name) VALUES ('Bob'), ('Fred')

-- I want to return all movies that include *any* of the above actors but exclude movies that have other actors in them.

SELECT m.Name
FROM [Character] c
    INNER JOIN Movie m ON c.Movie = m.Name
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Actor a ON c.Actor = a.Name
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @ActorNamesFilter filter ON a.Name = filter.Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive this from just the Character & filter tables [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ee730/4)

```
SELECT
      Character.Movie
FROM Character
LEFT JOIN ActorNamesFilter filter ON Character.Actor = filter.Name
GROUP BY
      Character.Movie
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Character.Actor) = COUNT(DISTINCT filter.name)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ee730/4/0)**:

```
|  Movie |
|--------|
| MovieA |
| MovieB |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT m.Name
FROM [Character] c INNER JOIN
     Movie m
     ON c.Movie = m.Name JOIN
     Actor a 
     ON c.Actor = a.Name JOIN
     @ActorNamesFilter filter
     ON a.Name = filter.Name
GROUP BY m.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @ActorNamesFilter);
```

This counts the number of actors in the film and then checks that the number of matches is the same as the number of names in the filter.

As a note:  If an actor can play multiple characters, then this should use `count(distinct)`:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.Name) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @ActorNamesFilter);
```

EDIT:

I think I misunderstood the original question.  The following ensures that all actors are specifically in the list of actors:

```
SELECT m.Name
FROM [Character] c LEFT JOIN
     Movie m
     ON c.Movie = m.Name LEFT JOIN
     Actor a 
     ON c.Actor = a.Name LEFT JOIN
     @ActorNamesFilter filter
     ON a.Name = filter.Name
GROUP BY m.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(filter.name) ;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/52d999/6) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: This returns MovieA and MovieC.   What should be returned is MovieA and MovieB.  MovieC has Sally in it - and she's not in the filter.